# Excel 2010: Create Graph From List

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, charts

I have created a drop down list for use in each row (for the purpose of categorising). I'd like to graph the selected data (i.e the column of drop down lists) into a graph, probably a pie chart.

If I set the column as the data source to the graph it puts the selected values into the title region.

Can someone provide me with a link to a web page on how to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would first create a table that calculates the data you need to display - with the given information I'm *assuming* this will be a list of the categories, along with the number of times each one appears in the data.

The easiest way to do this is via a PivotTable and Chart.

Otherwise, you can generate one yourself with a simple bit of fomula work - something like the below will total up the instances of each category (assuming the list is in col `E` on `OtherSheet` - adjust as required), which you should easily be able to build a pie chart from.

```
    A               B
1   ham             =COUNTIF(OtherSheet!E:E,A1)
2   cheese          =COUNTIF(OtherSheet!E:E,A2)
.
.
```

Comment: Spot on. Thanks - went for second option.